# NumberFormatException unable to parse xx as integer in AES128Bit in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to encrypt and decrypt my data in Android application. When I run the application it getting NumberFormatException (Unable to parse xx as integer) at the time of decryption. I've tried, but it does not decrypt my JSON string.

Here is my Activity code

```
jsonObject.put(KEY_REQUEST_ID, win2indiaPojo.getRequestId());
jsonObject.put(KEY_REQUEST_CODE, win2indiaPojo.getRequestCode());
jsonObject.put(KEY_CHANNEL_ID, win2indiaPojo.getChannelId());
jsonObject.put(KEY_IP_ADDRESS, win2indiaPojo.getIPAddress());
jsonObject.put(KEY_STATUS_FLAG, win2indiaPojo.getStatusFlag());
jsonObject.put(KEY_USERNAME, win2indiaPojo.getUserId());
jsonObject.put(KEY_PASSWORD, win2indiaPojo.getPassword());
json = jsonObject.toString();
System.out.println("json = " + json );

String encryptedJson="";

encryptedJson = SimpleCrypto.encrypt(json , key);
System.out.println("encryptedJson = " + encryptedJson );

JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();

inner.put(KEY_REQUEST, encryptedJson);
inner.put(KEY_VENDOR_ID, "1");

String strjson = "";
JSONObject outer = new JSONObject();

outer.put("W2INBCWS", inner);
strjson=outer.toString();
System.out.println("strjson  = " + strjson);

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(strjson);

System.out.println("StringEntity = " + se);
httpPost.setEntity(se);
System.out.println("httpPost Method !!!!!");
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String jsonString = reader.readLine();

jsonString=jsonString.replace("true", "\"true\"");

JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(jsonString);
JSONObject finalResult = new JSONObject(tokener);
String strFinalResult=finalResult.getString("Response");

System.out.println("Decrypted Values = ");

String decryptedString="";

decryptedString = SimpleCrypto.decrypt(strFinalResult, key);
System.out.println("decryptedString = " + decryptedString);
```

Here is Log cat info.

```
01-02 16:17:45.986: W/System.err(744): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'Dy' as integer
01-02 16:17:45.986: W/System.err(744):  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
01-02 16:17:45.994: W/System.err(744):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
01-02 16:17:45.994: W/System.err(744):  at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:528)
01-02 16:17:45.994: W/System.err(744):  at com.json_to_server.SimpleCrypto.toByte(SimpleCrypto.java:63)
01-02 16:17:45.994: W/System.err(744):  at com.json_to_server.SimpleCrypto.decrypt(SimpleCrypto.java:20)
01-02 16:17:46.004: W/System.err(744):  at com.json_to_server.EncryptDecrypt_Demo.POST(EncryptDecrypt_Demo.java:200)
01-02 16:17:46.004: W/System.err(744):  at com.json_to_server.EncryptDecrypt_Demo$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(EncryptDecrypt_Demo.java:257)
01-02 16:17:46.004: W/System.err(744):  at com.json_to_server.EncryptDecrypt_Demo$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(EncryptDecrypt_Demo.java:1)
01-02 16:17:46.004: W/System.err(744):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-02 16:17:46.004: W/System.err(744):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-02 16:17:46.004: W/System.err(744):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-02 16:17:46.004: W/System.err(744):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-02 16:17:46.004: W/System.err(744):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-02 16:17:46.014: W/System.err(744):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I'm getting the NuberFormatException at the line of `result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();`

```
public static byte[] toByte(String hexString)
{
    int len = hexString.length()/2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();

    return result;
}

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception
{
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);

    return new String(result);
}
```

Comment: Well, what did you expect when you tried to read `Dy` as hex?

Comment: @chrylis I,m using this String key="Dyv6ACIDe2q+OEjztjfNDw=="; for encrypt and decrypt of json data. I want to send encrypted data to server and want to get response as a decrypted from server.But it only encrypted.It can't decrypt and getting NumformatException.I have to use String key in=  encryptedJson = SimpleCrypto.encrypt(jsonObject.toString() , key);

Comment: @tazeenmulani I thnk when you are calling decrypt you are giving paramters in incorrect order. your code `decryptedString = SimpleCrypto.decrypt(strFinalResult, key);` but shouldn't it be `decryptedString = SimpleCrypto.decrypt(key, strFinalResult);` as strFinalResult is the encrypted content here?

Comment: @chrylis   JSONObject finalResult = new JSONObject(tokener);
            String strFinalResult=finalResult.getString("Response");  String decryptedString="";
          
            decryptedString = SimpleCrypto.decrypt(strFinalResult, key);

Comment: @tazeenmulani Can you post your strFinalResult value as well?

Comment: That's base64, not hex.

Comment: @chrylis This strFinalResult Value = 01-02 17:44:34.054: I/System.out(953): strFinalResultValue Values = {"Response":"NJGOkF2EvOIpfKG14LHQZrVfj\/OEJvopi+OKU+q5G2ynDbVUnIckfMLGCCsxcY9+BmVg+KJXF1ls\nGf2rWg73iyowyq6THyDfBS8uZnSp9PfS3bJCFb6YWX4\/\/uxjDwtZ","statusFlag":"true"}  and the exception at line = 01-02 17:44:34.054: W/System.err(953): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '{"' as integer

Comment: That means it is looking for a number

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem seems to be between the chair and the keyboard